# $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac {x^{4n}}{(2n)!}$ is Taylor's series of which function?

Tags: calculus, power-series

$\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac {x^{4n}}{(2n)!}$ 
 
a) $e^{x^4}$ 
b) $1+ x^2*\frac {\sin(x^2)}{2}$
c) $\cos^2(x^2)$
d) $(1+x^2)\ln(1+x^2)$ 
e) $\frac {1}{2} (e^{x^2} + e^{-x^2})$ 

What I tried to do: since $e^x$ Taylor series is $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac {x^{n}}{n!}$, I'm gonna investigate the options (a) and (e) first. 
(a) $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac {x^{4n}}{n!}$ , if we substitute ($x^4$). 
(e) if $e^x$ Taylor series is $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac {x^{n}}{n!}$, then $e^{-x}$ Taylor series is $\sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac {(-x)^{n}}{n!} = \sum^\infty_{n=0}\frac {(-1)^nx^{n}}{n!}$, from here I tried to do $\frac {e^x + e^{-x}}{2}$, and I realized I have no idea how to calculate these sums. 
 
I also couldn't think of similar ways to write the series of (b)(c)(d), I would appreciate any help if there's an easy way to find these functions series without having to take derivatives, just using the know Taylor's series for known functions, (if it's not possible I would appreciate any help of how to reach a $\sum$  from just calculating derivatives and substituting in Taylor's polynomials formula). 
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do addition on this sums as you would do on finite sums, at least in this case where they converge everywhere.

Hence, for (e), you can keep pushing your initial idea:

$e^{x^2} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{n!}$ and $e^{-x^2} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-x^2)^n}{n!}$

So now $e^{x^2} + e^{-x^2} = \dots$ and you can add "term-by-term" the Taylor series and see where this leads you.

Comment: this is leading me to get the terms with the even powers multiplied by 2 each one, it's either I'm making lots of mistakes or how should I reach the $x^{4n}$?

Comment: Can you write exactly what you managed to obtain ? You probably have the right result, and some manipulation of indices or simply rewriting the exponents should give the final result.

Comment: Hey sorry for replying too late, It's all good now, I was messing up with the powers, Appreciate the help :)

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

$$e^y=\sum_{r=0}^\infty\dfrac{y^r}{r!}$$

Replace $y$ with $x^2,-x^2$ one by one to find $e^{x^2}+e^{-x^2}$

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the Maclaurin series (or Taylor series if you prefer) of $\cosh x$ is:
$$\cosh x=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2r}}{(2r)!}$$
Replace $x$ by $x^2$ and we find that
$$\cosh x^2=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{4r}}{(2r)!}$$

Answer (score 0):

Since $e^x=\sum_{n\ge0}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$, what we have here is  $e)$, or the "odd terms" of $e^{x^2}$.